# How to make Empathy run on startup?

Tags: gnome, empathy, startup-applications

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I'd like Empathy to connect when I login to my computer.

I know I can browse using the Startup Applications tool (although the add/browse dialogue is still useless in GNOME 3), but is there a better way?

Comment: i think that would be be the best way to do it. but if there a better way ill post it below

Answer (score 13):

You can use `-h` option to start hidden, i.e., no contacts window at startup

Add Empathy to startup and remember to have `Connect on Startup`(which is enabled by default) checked in `Empathy` -> `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Behaviour`
[image: How to do it]